# Return a promise from service

Tags: angularjs

I have this service where I do like this

```
userRes.getCurrentUser = () => {
    return userRes.get({
        user: 1
    });
};
```

Which I use in my controller like this

```
console.log(currUserService.getCurrentUser());
```

and it works fine, I get back a promise and the object when it is resolved

BUT

I want to create a class after I get the data, so I do like this

```
userRes.getCurrentUser = () => {
    userRes.get({
        user: 1
    }).$promise.then(data => {
        return new User(data);
    });
};
```

But then I get `undefined`

How can I make it return the class?

Thank you

**Edit**

```
let userRes = $resource('url', {}, {});
```

Comment: return userRes.get, here is a useful link about promises https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly `userRes` is, but in general, `.then()` returns its promise chain.

Changing

```
userRes.getCurrentUser = () => {
    userRes.get({
        user: 1
    }).$promise.then(data => {
        return new User(data);
    });
};
```

to

```
userRes.getCurrentUser = () => {
    return userRes.get({ // !! Notice the return statement here
        user: 1
    }).$promise.then(data => {
        return new User(data);
    });
};
```

will give you the promise chain, which you can add another `.then()` onto  to utilize the new `User` returned previously.

Answer (score 0):

In your last example it doesn't return anything, you should return a Promise there by adding `return`.

After you return `Promise<User>` in the service, in the class where you call it, you should do something like this:

```
var userPromise = currUserService.getCurrentUser(); // Promise<User> type
userPromise.then(user => { /* do something with the user when it is resolved*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller script,  currUserService.getCurrentUser() will run through the function without handling the promise. In fact it will return nothing.

```
 console.log(currUserService.getCurrentUser());
```

to properly use the $promise, you can return the $promise, as in

```
return userRes.getCurrentUser = () => {
    userRes.get({
    user: 1
}).$promise.then(data => {
    return new User(data);
});  // end of this chain is another $promise
```

};

now in your controller you can do this

```
currUserService.getCurrentUser().then( user =>{
    console.log(user);
});
```